# Publishing publishing chromium - desktop web-app to Ubuntu Software center?

Tags: software-center, chromium, packaging, license

does anyone knows whether chromium based applications are accepted by Ubuntu? I was reading the entire 'developer' section but couldn't get a glue yet.

My mix is: PHP/NGINX/Node-JS for server side, and packaged as 'electron' - chromium app for the client. It's basically a pre-compiled all-in-one package(deb) and I managed to make the server dependencies variable (light-http/apache/nginx) in the deb config.

Does that will be actually accepted on the license side? My source code licenses are GPL-2/BSD dual from my side, and the rest is GPL/MIT/BSD/Apache,... too. In the guide-lines, that is ok.

I am just not sure about chromium-embedded ('electron app') but as last instance, you can open in the default browser as well.

The point of this post is to figure out possible problems, Apple and others didn't gave exactly positive examples when it comes to 'App-Store'. That's the more main concern I have.

However, I searched the Ubuntu forum for : publishing, node js, packaging but there wasn't much about. I checked SO too, but same. Seems all possible and 'easy'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, Ubuntu Software Center is deprecated and will [soon be removed from Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/11/the-ubuntu-software-centre-is-being-replace-in-16-04-lts). Currently Ubuntu is working on integrating the GNOME Software Center into Ubuntu, and will be developing a method to integrate its upcoming snappy app packaging system into the GNOME Software Center. 
 As far as electron-based app submissions are concerned, I don't think there should be a huge problem if, in the end, it is just a deb file or snappy package.  At the same time, I could be wrong and it would be better to ask a more credible source about that. 
 I would suggest talking to some developers who have deployed and maintain packages in the Ubuntu Software Center. 
 Plus, you could also just simply offer a PPA or a deb file for download on a website, or from Github (like for example, Github does for its Atom text editor, which is another Electron based app).

Comment: nice, thanks a lot. I will leave it open for now, may be others can add more.

Comment: No problems. Glad I could help. :)